# Offset argument contained a NaN value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a draggable widget in a stack. Every time I restart the application and  initiates state , it gives me "Offset argument contained a NaN value " .

The Main Activity contains the stack of tab bar and the dragggable helping widget. I give the draggable widget initial position of offset(300,300) to be at the bottom right of the page.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:marqoum/Bookmarks.dart';
import 'Helper.dart';
import 'PdfViewPage.dart';
import 'HelpingList.dart';

class MainActivityPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String path;

  const MainActivityPage({Key key, this.path}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return bMainActivityPage();
  }
}

class bMainActivityPage extends State<MainActivityPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  static final myTabbedPageKey = new GlobalKey<bMainActivityPage>();

  TabController etabController;

  bool isClicked = false;
  int delay = 1000;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    etabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    etabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> myTabs = [PdfViewPage(path: widget.path), Bookmarks()];

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: TabBar(
              controller: etabController,
              onTap: (tappedPage) {
                setState(() {
                  if (tappedPage == 1) {
                    print("Hi one");
                  }
                });
              },
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  text: 'الكتاب ',
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.picture_as_pdf,
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'المفضلة ',
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.bookmark_border,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
              labelColor: Color(0xfffc3b398),
              indicatorColor: Color(0xfffc3b398),
              indicatorWeight: 2,
            ),
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              TabBarView(
                controller: etabController,
                children: myTabs,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              ),
              Helper(
                initPos: Offset(232, 2),
                isPressed: (bool isPressed) {
                  setState(() {
                    isClicked = isPressed;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Visibility(
                child: HelpingList(),
                visible: isClicked,
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

The draggable

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
class Helper extends StatefulWidget {
  //DECLARING THE HELPING WIDGET INITIAL POSITION
  final Offset initPos;
  final Function(bool ispressed) isPressed;

  //INITIAL POITION'S CONSTRUCTOR
  Helper({this.initPos, this.isPressed});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _helper();
  }
}

class _helper extends State<Helper> {
  Offset position ;
  double height = 50, width = 50;
  bool isclicked = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    position = widget.initPos;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        left: position.dx,
        top: position.dy,
        child: Draggable(
            child: helpingButton(),
            onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
              setState(() {
                isclicked = false;
                widget.isPressed(isclicked);
                height = 50;
                width = 50;
                position = offset;
              });
            },
            feedback: feedBackHelpingButton()));
  }

  Widget helpingButton() {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInSine,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfffc3b398),
        child: helpingIcon(),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isclicked = true;
            isclicked
                ? {
                    height = 100,
                    width = 100,
                    widget.isPressed(isclicked),
                    position = Offset(150, 150),
                  }
                : {
                    isclicked = false,
                  };
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget helpingIcon() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.list,
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }

  Widget feedBackHelpingButton() {
    return Container(
        height: height + 10,
        width: width + 10,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xfffc3b398).withOpacity(0.5),
          child: helpingIcon(),
          onPressed: () {
            return null;
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

```
D/jniPdfium(12697): Destroy FPDF library
W/libEGL  (12697): EGLNativeWindowType 0x71ea582010 disconnect failed
Restarted application in 1,865ms.
I/flutter (12697): /data/user/0/com.example.marqoum/app_flutter/test.pdf
V/AudioManager(12697): playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
E/BufferQueueProducer(12697): [] [hwsched]Can not get hwsched service
D/CubicBezierInterpolator(12697): CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
D/CubicBezierInterpolator(12697): CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
D/CubicBezierInterpolator(12697): CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
D/CubicBezierInterpolator(12697): CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
D/com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore(12697): Starting PdfiumAndroid 1.9.0
D/HwRTBlurUtils(12697): check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x0103023e, context : android.app.Presentation$3@616db92, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
D/HwRTBlurUtils(12697): check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x0103023e, context : android.app.Presentation$3@616db92, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
D/OpenGLRenderer(12697):   HWUI Binary is  enabled
I/PressGestureDetector(12697): HiTouch restricted: Sub windows restricted.
D/jniPdfium(12697): Init FPDF library
D/mali_winsys(12697): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/OpenGLRenderer(12697):   HWUI Binary is  enabled
I/flutter (12697): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12697): The following assertion was thrown during paint():
I/flutter (12697): Offset argument contained a NaN value.
I/flutter (12697): 'dart:ui/painting.dart': Failed assertion: line 38: '<optimized out>'
I/flutter (12697):
I/flutter (12697): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (12697): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (12697): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (12697):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (12697):
I/flutter (12697): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (12697): #2      _offsetIsValid  (dart:ui/painting.dart:38:10)
I/flutter (12697): #3      Canvas.drawCircle  (dart:ui/painting.dart:3382:12)
I/flutter (12697): #4      _BoxDecorationPainter._paintBox 
I/flutter (12697): #5      _BoxDecorationPainter._paintBackgroundColor 
I/flutter (12697): #6      _BoxDecorationPainter.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #7      RenderDecoratedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #8      RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #9      PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #10     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #11     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #12     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #13     RenderShiftedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #14     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #15     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #16     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #17     RenderFractionalTranslation.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #18     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #19     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #20     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #21     RenderTransform.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #22     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #23     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #24     _RenderLayoutBuilder.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #25     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #26     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #27     _RenderStack&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint 
I/flutter (12697): #28     RenderStack.paintStack 
I/flutter (12697): #29     RenderStack.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #30     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #31     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #32     RenderShiftedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #33     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #34     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #35     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #36     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #37     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #38     RenderShiftedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #39     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #40     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #41     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #42     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #43     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #44     RenderShiftedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #45     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #46     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #47     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #48     RenderDecoratedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #49     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #50     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #51     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #52     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #53     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #54     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #55     RenderPointerListener.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #56     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #57     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #58     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #59     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #60     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #61     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #62     RenderDecoratedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #63     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #64     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #65     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #66     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #67     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #68     RenderShiftedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #69     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #70     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #71     RenderShiftedBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #72     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #73     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #74     _RenderStack&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint 
I/flutter (12697): #75     RenderStack.paintStack 
I/flutter (12697): #76     RenderStack.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #77     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #78     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #79     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #80     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #81     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #82     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #83     PaintingContext._compositeChild 
I/flutter (12697): #84     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #85     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #86     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #87     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #88     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #89     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #90     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #91     RenderViewportBase._paintContents 
I/flutter (12697): #92     PaintingContext.pushLayer 
I/flutter (12697): #93     PaintingContext.pushClipRect 
I/flutter (12697): #94     RenderViewportBase.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #95     RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #96     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #97     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #98     PaintingContext._compositeChild 
I/flutter (12697): #99     PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #100    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #101    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #102    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #103    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #104    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #105    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #106    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #107    RenderPointerListener.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #108    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #109    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #110    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #111    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #112    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #113    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #114    RenderPointerListener.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #115    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #116    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #117    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #118    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #119    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #120    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #121    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #122    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): [onPageChanged, {total: 22, page: 0}]
I/flutter (12697): [onRender, {pages: 22}]
I/flutter (12697): [onPageChanged, {total: 22, page: 0}]
I/flutter (12697): [onPageChanged, {total: 22, page: 0}]
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:124)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:204)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at io.endigo.plugins.pdfviewflutter.FlutterPDFView.setPage(FlutterPDFView.java:119)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at io.endigo.plugins.pdfviewflutter.FlutterPDFView.onMethodCall(FlutterPDFView.java:102)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:88)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:219)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.endigo.io/pdfview_0(12697):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
E/DartMessenger(12697): Uncaught exception in binary message listener
E/DartMessenger(12697): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:124)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:219)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:88)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:219)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
E/DartMessenger(12697):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
I/flutter (12697): #123    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #124    PaintingContext._compositeChild 
I/flutter (12697): #125    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #126    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #127    RenderCustomPaint.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #128    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #129    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #130    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #131    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #132    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #133    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #134    PaintingContext._compositeChild 
I/flutter (12697): #135    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #136    _RenderStack&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint 
I/flutter (12697): #137    RenderStack.paintStack 
I/flutter (12697): #138    RenderStack.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #139    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #140    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #141    _RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint 
I/flutter (12697): #142    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #143    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #144    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #145    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #146    _RenderInkFeatures.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #147    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #148    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #149    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #150    PaintingContext.pushLayer 
I/flutter (12697): #151    RenderPhysicalModel.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #152    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #153    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #154    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #155    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #156    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #157    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #158    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #159    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #160    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #161    PaintingContext._compositeChild 
I/flutter (12697): #162    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #163    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #164    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #165    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #166    RenderAnimatedOpacity.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #167    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #168    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #169    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #170    RenderFractionalTranslation.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #171    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #172    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #173    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #174    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #175    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #176    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #177    PaintingContext._compositeChild 
I/flutter (12697): #178    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #179    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #180    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #181    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #182    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #183    RenderOffstage.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #184    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #185    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #186    _RenderStack&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint 
I/flutter (12697): #187    RenderStack.paintStack 
I/flutter (12697): #188    RenderStack.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #189    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #190    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #191    __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #192    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #193    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #194    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #195    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #196    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #197    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #198    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #199    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #200    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #201    RenderPointerListener.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #202    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #203    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #204    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #205    RenderCustomPaint.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #206    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #207    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #208    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #209    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #210    PaintingContext.paintChild 
I/flutter (12697): #211    RenderView.paint 
I/flutter (12697): #212    RenderObject._paintWithContext 
I/flutter (12697): #213    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #214    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild 
I/flutter (12697): #215    PipelineOwner.flushPaint 
I/flutter (12697): #216    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame 
I/flutter (12697): #217    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame 
I/flutter (12697): #218    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback 
I/flutter (12697): #219    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback 
I/flutter (12697): #220    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame 
I/flutter (12697): #221    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame 
I/flutter (12697): #225    _invoke  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:10)
I/flutter (12697): #226    _drawFrame  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:178:3)
I/flutter (12697): (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
I/flutter (12697):
I/flutter (12697): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter (12697):   RenderDecoratedBox#0f20d
I/flutter (12697):   creator: DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← CircleThumb ← Center ← FractionalTranslation
I/flutter (12697):   ← Transform ← LayoutBuilder ← Stack ← Padding ← AspectRatio ← Center ← ⋯
I/flutter (12697):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter (12697):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=20.0, h=20.0)
I/flutter (12697):   size: Size(20.0, 20.0)
I/flutter (12697):   decoration: BoxDecoration
I/flutter (12697):   configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#0f312(), devicePixelRatio: 3.0,
I/flutter (12697):   locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
I/flutter (12697): This RenderObject has no descendants.
I/flutter (12697): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12697): Another exception was thrown: Offset argument contained a NaN value.
I/flutter (12697): Another exception was thrown: Offset argument contained a NaN value.
```

Answer (score 2):

Error `NaN` could be caused by dividing by a variable which cannot be cast to a numbe as.

Flutter does not throw an error while dividing by 0. So you can check `NaN` with:

```
if (number == double.nan)
```